# Straight up convert NSNumber to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

How to?

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *seasonRoundN;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *seasonRound;
```

.m

```
_weMeetAgain = [NSNumber numberWithInt:13];
_seasonRound = [NSString stringWithFormat:_weMeetAgain]; // incompatible :S
```

Should have looked at the reference better: (Answer below)

```
_weMeetAgain = [NSNumber numberWithInt:17];
_seasonRound = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _weMeetAgain];
```

Help :P, thank you.

Comment: `_seasonRoung = [_weMeetAgain stringValue];`

Answer (score 5):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [_weMeetAgain intValue]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use NSNumber instance method [stringValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/stringValue).

```
_seasonRound = [_weMeetAgain stringValue];
```